# Google charts -- different x-axis label and data label

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to display some statistics. I'm using column chart. Each column has a label, which is a very long string. This label is displayed as x-axis label and also when I hover over the data column. What I would like to do is to keep this long label displayed when hovering over the column but display just ID on the x-axis. For instance:

```
ID | Name            | Value
1  | Some long label | 3.0
```

I want the "ID" as x-axis label and "Name" to be displayed when hovering over the data column. "Value" is the actual data. Is it possible to do this? I wasn't able to find this in the Charts documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use DataTable roles and in your case the [tooltip](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole) role that is supported but the [column chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).